# How to write a nested macro that prints its own suffix?

Tags: clojure, macros

I am trying to better understand [listing 13.3 in The Joy of Clojure](https://github.com/joyofclojure/book-source/blob/master/src/joy/measures.clj#L16).  It is a macro that generates other macros (much like how primitive array functions are implemented in Clojure 1.4).

I want to write a macro that, when run, simply prints the suffix of the generated macro. i.e.

```
user=> (nested-macro joe)
user=> (nested-macro-named-joe)
hello from joe
nil
```

I am having trouble making this work.

Here is what I've tried:

**Attempt 1**

```
(defmacro nested-macro [name]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "nested-macro-named-" name))
     []
     `(println "hello from " ~name)))
```

*Output:*

`hello from  #<core$name clojure.core$name@502c06b2>`

**Attempt 2**

```
(defmacro nested-macro [name]
  (let [local-name name]
    `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "my-custom-macro-named-" ~local-name))
       []
       `(println "hello from " ~local-name))))
```

*Error*

`IllegalStateException Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/unquote  clojure.lang.Var$Unbound.throwArity (Var.java:43)`

**Attempt 3:**

```
(defmacro nested-macro [name]
  (let [local-name name]
    `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "nested-macro-named-" name))
       []
       `(println "hello from " ~(symbol local-name)))))
```

*Compiler Error:*

`CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: joy.dsl/local-name`

Just for the heck of it, I've also tried adding `#` to the local variables, with similar results as above but with "auto" names, such as `local-name__1127__auto__` I don't see that being as part of the solution, however.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know what is going wrong with macros I always use `macroexpand-1`.

From your first example:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(nested-macro joe))
```

Results in:

```
(clojure.core/defmacro nested-macro-named-joe [] 
  (clojure.core/seq 
    (clojure.core/concat 
      (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/println)) 
      (clojure.core/list "hello from ") 
      (clojure.core/list clojure.core/name))))
```

If you look at the last param, it shows that you are using clojure.core/name, which probably is not what you want, as you actually want the parameter named "name".

To fix it, just add another unquote to the `name` param, but as the name param is actually a symbol, what you really want is to get the name of it as in:

```
(defmacro nested-macro [the-name]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (str "nested-macro-named-" the-name))
     []
     `(println "hello from " ~~(name the-name))))
```

Comment: `'~~name` is a more general solution to quoting in similar situations - it's not always the case that you're happy to get a string representation of the value.

Comment: Replacing ~~(name the-name) for '~~name results in a `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: joe in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)`.

Comment: Ugh, nested quoting is hard. I guess it's `'~'~name` to stop the inner macro from attempting to resolve the name.

Comment: Thanks, I think I now understand nested quoting. Next up: `&env` and `&form`